# ViewModel not populated after the form is submitted using ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My view model is not getting populated when I submit the form using the ActionLink. Here is jquery code to submit the form:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        // attach the event to submit the form when button is clicked 

        $("#lnkSubmit").click(function () {

            // submit the form 
            $("#CustomerRequestForm").submit(); 

        });

    });
```

Onsubmit the controller action is called but all the properties of the viewmodel are null.

UPDATE 1:

here is the form code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCustomer","Customer",FormMethod.Post,new { id = "CustomerRequestForm" }))
```

Comment: have you used Html.BeginForm() in your view

Comment: Need more info. I do not see the problem in the code you have posted.

Comment: yes I have used html.beginform which invokes the correct action

Comment: do I have to use the Ajax.beginform for the binding to work!

Comment: no one has this problem before! that is kinda weird!

Comment: @johndoe, no people who respect web standards (using submit buttons to submit forms) don't have such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question with the following disclaimer:

**Use submit buttons to submit forms, not links**

This being said, make sure to cancel the default link action by returning false or you will get redirected before the form even had time to submit:

```
$("#lnkSubmit").click(function () {
    $("#CustomerRequestForm").trigger('submit'); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why use .Trigger() over .Submit()?

Comment: @Pino, no particular reason. Just wanted to change something :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you do is submit when clicking on an URL, why not use a button? They are made for that and people get what they do.

If you need to redirect to an other page. do it after the form is submitted and the code has run. (in your return)

Comment: Using a link is a requirement! What can I say?

Comment: @johndoe, I wonder what kind of illiterates impose such requirements. Definitely people knowing nothing about web standards. Those people could be cheated with CSS and images. So you could make a submit button (the only semantically correct element used to submit html forms) look like a link.

Comment: I agree man! that is what I am telling them for the last 2 days!

Comment: @Darin IMO asthetics and behavior should really be seperate.  The asthetics of a link and a button shouldn't be tied to a specific behavior.  Why is it images can behave like a href or trigger a postback, but links can only be hrefs and buttons only postbacks?

Comment: @AaronLS, because that's how the HTML 4.01 specification was written. You should ask the W3C working group about their decisions.

Comment: @Darin It was a rhetorical question.  My point being that there is no consistency regarding the standard tieing the behavior and aesthetics together for links and buttons, but not following that same convention for other elements.